# Match all lines after the first line that contains

Tags: regex

I am looking to match all lines after the first line that contains a known string, including the full line containing that string

I got as far as [this](https://regex101.com/r/WdW9Ve/2):

```
((?=202099T19:11:49\+00:00)).*
```

Input text:

```
45op0   202056T20:48:33+00:00   113-646536-035644   
trico   202023T19:48:32+00:00   11434491-8205047    JJBBe
202024T19:22:41+00:00   111-402297  
tyuh   202099T19:11:49+00:00    113-4997
tyuh   202099T19:11:49+00:00    113-4997
202076T17:59:47+00:00   114-4625200-7   
acure   202011T17:55:01+00:00   112-3296056-6611    
202009T17:52:10+00:00   113-4271010
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Which language you're working with ? does the `.` in your regex flavour matches new line as well ?

Comment: `(?-s).*(?s)202099T19:11:49\+00:00.*`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQSaVu/2). Or plainly `.*202099T19:11:49\+00:00[\s\S]*` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQSaVu/3).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove the `s` modifier that makes `.` match across lines and use `.*` to match any 0+ chars on a single line where the match is, and `[\s\S]*` to match any 0+ chars as many as possible including line breaks on the right hand side:

```
.*202099T19:11:49\+00:00[\s\S]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQSaVu/3)

Or, you may use `(?s)` (enables DOTALL mode) / `(?-s)` (disables DOTALL mode) inline modifiers (that are not that portable unfortunately):

```
.*(?s)202099T19:11:49\+00:00.*
```

Here, `(?s)` turns the DOTALL mode on to allow `.` match line breaks.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQSaVu/4)

Comment: I am also looking to match all lines from the beginning until the last line that contains the known string, including the full line containing that string; in the same test string. I am working on this right now. Since I have you here, again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @fionpo You already have the tools you need, see https://regex101.com/r/SQSaVu/5

Comment: Right, thanks for the example. Unfortunately 202011T17:55:01+00:00 is not known. Only one value is know, which is 202099T19:11:49+00:00

Comment: @fionpo Sorry, I am afraid you should handle that on your own, as this is not clear. You wrote *I am also looking to match all lines from the beginning until the last line that contains the **known string***. Just use your known value, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQSaVu/6)

Comment: It would match what is shown at https://regex101.com/r/SQSaVu/7 but nothing in the first line is known. The match would end in the last occurrence of the line that contains 202099T19:11:49+00:00 including that line

Comment: @fionpo You say nothing in the first line is known, then where is `45op0` from? Sorry, please check your requirements, then come back if you still have any questions.

Comment: Right, basically it needs to match everything from the top until the line that last line that contains 202099T19:11:49+00:00, including that line. So (?s) will not work in this case, at least to get all lines until the last one that contains 202099T19:11:49+00:00. I am working on it and will come back if I need a last push. Thank you so much

Comment: @fionpo `\A[\s\S]*202099T19:11:49\+00:00.*`

Comment: I put 45op0 in there, just to show you what needs to be matched in the test string. But in the real world it could be anything

Comment: Wow, I was close. I was missing the \A. I will study these examples, so hopefully will need less help moving forward. Thanks again